# Recommend me ways to route my PDF file to another service

Tags: kotlin, jvm, micronaut, ktor

I am writing a backend code in kotlin/micronaut. The scenario which I am facing is that my backend will recieve a PDF file from client and I have to redirect that PDF file to another endpoint(This endpoint is in another service). So to deal this I am using Ktor. But it is throwing me an error. My code is

```
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.request.forms.*
import io.ktor.client.request.post
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.util.*
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post
import io.micronaut.http.multipart.CompletedFileUpload
import io.micronaut.security.annotation.Secured
import io.micronaut.security.rules.SecurityRule

@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
@Controller("/pdf-extract")
class PdfService(private val ktorClient: HttpClient) {

    @Post(value = "/", consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON])
    suspend fun pdfService(@Body files: CompletedFileUpload): String {
        val response = uploadFileToExternalService(files)
        return if (response.code() == 200) {
            "Response from API: ${response.body()}"
        } else {
            "Failed to fetch data from API"
        }
    }

    @OptIn(InternalAPI::class)
    suspend fun uploadFileToExternalService(file: CompletedFileUpload): HttpResponse<String> {
        return try {
            val response = ktorClient.post<String>("http://127.0.0.1:8000/file/") {
                body = MultiPartFormDataContent(formData {
                    append("file", file.inputStream, Headers.build {
                        append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, file.contentType.toString())
                        append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${file.name}")
                    })
                })
            }
            HttpResponse.ok(response)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            HttpResponse.serverError("Failed to upload file: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
}
```

The error which I am getting is

```
"Failed to inject value for parameter [ktorClient] of class: dk.controllers.PdfService\r\n\r\nMessage: No bean of type [io.ktor.client.HttpClient] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).\r\nPath Taken: new PdfService(HttpClient ktorClient) --> new PdfService([HttpClient ktorClient])"
```

Is there any other way to do this or if Ktor is a good approach, then how to solve the above mentioned issue.